# Axon - JPA Event store for MySql

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, axon

I'm trying to implement Axon app using JPA Event Store and mysql database. Hibernate is automatically generating all the tables and it works OK so far.

My question is - can I replace hibernate_sequence mysql table for `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns in Mysql. I guess in order to do this I would need to modify source code of Axon, since I cannot find other configurable way to modify `@Id` annotation for Domain event `@Entity` or other entitites?

**UPDATE**

OK, i managed to do it by placing new file in `src\main\resources\META-INF\orm.xml`  with following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
                 version="2.0">

    <mapped-superclass class="org.axonframework.eventhandling.AbstractSequencedDomainEventEntry" access="FIELD">
        <attributes>
            <id name="globalIndex">
                <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY"/>
            </id>
        </attributes>
    </mapped-superclass>

    <entity class="org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.jpa.AssociationValueEntry" access="FIELD">
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY"/>
            </id>
        </attributes>
    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make this adjustment through code, that's true.
It is however more straightforward to specify an `orm.xml` file in your project which for some tables (the `domain_event_entry` table in your scenario I assume) can adjust certain columns.
In there you should be able to adjust the sequence generator to what you desire it to be.

Hope this helps!